# Creating a profile or template for Word 2007 to use on different computers?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I work in an office settings where a user may find himself sitting at a different computer on any given day of the week.

Using Word 2007 (at the office), I often customize the Quick Access Toolbar prior to using Word. But, to have to do this on every computer is tedious.

Is there a way to save a template or profile of some sort which I can download to our network's z: drive and then later upload to another computer that I find myself using on another day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me like your only solution is to replace the *.qat files containing the settings for the Quick Access Toolbar. You could create scripts to save the existing file and copy your own in-place, and vice-verso.

For the placement of the *.qat files,
from the article
[Deploy Quick Access Toolbar customizations by using the Office Customization Tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347467%28v=office.12%29.aspx),
section "Adding support for roaming users" :

> Before you enable support for roaming users the default folder for
>   *.qat settings files is in the local area of a user profile, as follows:
>
> ```
> Windows XP:
> %USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Office
>
> Windows Vista:
> %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office
> ```
>
> After you enable support for roaming users the default folder for
>   *.qat settings files for all platforms is:
>
> ```
> %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Office
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much. Not something I can do as an end user, but I have informed my administrator of this solution.